# Huge delay after exchange ssh keys (via git)

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I have more than one github account, so to manage them via ssh I put two different entries inside `~/.ssh/config` file.

This is one of them:

```
Host github_second_account
    User git
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_second_account
```

This worked fine until last week.
Now I'm having huge delays when doing a simple git fetch/pull/push

So in order to test what's wroing, I use -vv in a simple connection:

```
ssh -vvT github_second_account
```

This is the result:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/myuser/.ssh/github_second_account': 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([ip]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done

// HUGE DELAY HERE (at least 10 minutes): 
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1

debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 97
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 6/(97)
Hi myuser! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

The delay starts after It successfully autenticate, specially this two events takes 10 minutes to resolve (each one):

```
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this? I'm running out of ideas.

My system:

- Manjaro 21.0 Ornara
- Shell: zsh 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following many tips online and doing a lot of try and error, I find a solution by modifying the system file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Just added this option at the end of the file:

```
IPQoS 0x00
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first, considering there [was an incident yesterday](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/qbxxqgbh3x5c), if:

- the issue persists
- the issue is reproductible on a different computer/OS

That way, you can rule out or pinpoint the issue on your specific second GitHub account.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue does not persist any more, however, despite the fact that it presented only on my computer/OS, and considering that it verifies not only on github but also on a git repository on a third party server I'm considering that it wasn't linked with the github incident. I wrote my "presumable" solution